# Why do we need continuity at the end points of the interval for Rolle's theorem?

Tags: functions, rolles-theorem, mean-value-theorem

For a function ($f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$) to satisfy Rolle's theorem it must be continuous in the interval $[a,b]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $f(a)=f(b)$. I don't really understand what's the need of function being continuous at $x=a$ and at $x=b$.

Because even if the functions are not continuous at $ a,b$ then also I can get a '$c$' in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$ by just replacing the third condition written above with
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x \to b}f(x)$$

So is there any specific reason to define continuity at the end points?

Comment: Have you looked at a proof of Rolle's theorem? The continuity of $f$ at $a$ and $b$ really is necessary.

Comment: Take $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(x)=x+2$ for $x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: If your alternative condition is satisfied, you can (re)define $f$ at the endpoints so that it becomes continuous on $[a,b]$ with $f(a)=f(b)$, so what's the difference, really?

Comment: @Hans Lundmark but doesn't that mean that this definition is more general ?

Comment: Yes, but not in a way that really matters, since if you are ever in a situation where your hypotheses are satisfied but not the original ones, then you can just redefine the function so that the original hypotheses *become* satisfied. That is, you apply the original theorem to a redefined function in order to get the conclusion that you want for the function that you actually have. So there are no cases that your new version can handle that couldn't easily have been handled using the original formulation of the theorem anyway.

Comment: To clarify, are you also asking why continuity at the endpoints is assumed, how it is used in the proof?

Comment: @FShrike Actually yes.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, you mentioned you wanted to know why continuity at the endpoints is needed for the proof.

I will show why that is with two counterexamples. It's all about the extreme value theorem.

---

By the way, it's worth also noting that $f(a)=f(b)$ does not mean $\lim_{x\to a}f(a)=\lim_{x\to b}f(x)$. The definition of limit actually means that neither limit actually involves the values $f(a)$ or $f(b)$ so there is no reason to expect it to be true. And it is false: take $$f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R,\,\,x\mapsto \begin{cases}0&x=0,1\\1-2x&0<x<1\end{cases}$$

The limit as $x\to a=0$ is $1$ but the limit as $x\to b=1$ is $-1$.

---

I will use this same $f$ for my first counterexample. So, $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)$. On the interior, $f'(x)=-2$ always - it is never zero. So what went wrong? The standard proof of Rolle's theorem begins with:

> Because $f$ is continuous and $[a,b]$ is compact, $f$ **attains** a **maximum** and **minimum** value on this interval (a.k.a the extreme value theorem)

Notice that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)=1$ and $\inf_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)=-1$ but $f$ is never equal to $1$ or $-1$. So here the upper bounds do exist - $f$ has a *supremum* -  but it never attains a *maximum*. So we can't pick $\xi\in(0,1)$ a extremal point and use the usual argumentation to find $f'(\xi)=0$. The openness of $(0,1)$ allows for $f$ to be always decreasing without ever reaching its lower limits. The closedness of $[0,1]$ eliminates/helps to eliminate that possibility, which is why it is important that $f$ be continuous on all of $[0,1]$ in Rolle's theorem.

Now for another example. Let: $$f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R,\,x\mapsto\begin{cases}0&x=0,1\\\cot\pi x&0<x<1\end{cases}$$

$f$ is again differentiable on the interior and $f(0)=f(1)$. But $f$ is not continuous at the endpoints, and in fact $f$ does not have any upper or lower bounds! The extreme value theorem fails even more significantly in this example. $f'$ is never zero. A lack of continuity at the endpoints leaves open the possibility that $f$ is unbounded, which is a different problem to the nuance between being bounded but not *attaining* that bound.

The extreme value theorem is so useful because it gives both a bound and an attaining of that bound. Weaken the hypotheses at your peril!